# Resize scrollable div on menu open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/n97ff4vc/2/

I want to prevent the `.context-table-container` from covering the `.footer` area when the "Advanced search" and the top menus are open.

Ideally, it should resize itself to the remaining area between the "Advanced search" menu and the footer.

How can I achieve this with css?

Comment: Even if you post a live example, some code on this page would be great.

Comment: The thing is : you used absolute positionning everywhere, even if sometimes you shouldn't. It makes things more complex...

Comment: I see, why I shouldn't use absolute positioning? I specified the positioning on 2 element, could you provide a solution which doesn't use absolute positioning?

Comment: As you're layout seems to use a normal HTML float, you shouldn't need absolute positionning that much. I'm not telling you not to use it, but to use it when you really need it :)

Comment: I'm not really into this CSS stuff, if you could provide an example without absolute positioning, that'd be great!

Comment: I'm on it, but it can take some time :)

Comment: That was tricky, and interesting. My answer is below. I bookmarked this thread as I certainly need to reuse my code in the future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried something with `display: table;` layout, here's a live example :**

http://jsfiddle.net/n97ff4vc/5/

*As you can see, I'm using inner properties of display: table, and display: table-row, to give a "fluid height", or an height that is relative to the parent height and its children...*

Note that I broke some of the original styles in the operation (I needed to clean some stuff)...

Comment: I'll probably open a new question for this, but padding-left: 10px; is ignored in `display: table`.

Answer (score -1):

1st Method : add this to your css

```
.footer{z-index:999; width: 100% ; background-color: #444;}
```

2nd Method ( i recommend this ) : add this to your css

```
 div.sidebar.closed > ul:nth-child(4) {max-height: 100%;}
.footer{width: 100% ; background-color: #444;}
```

Comment: But the scrollbar will be under the footer then ?

Comment: Why put such a high z-index? That seems unnecessary.
(p.s. I didn't down-vote you)

Comment: This hides the scrollable area instead of resizing it.